# SQL update query is wrongly picking SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update the `last_update_date` column using the below SQL query but Oracle is picking the `SYSDATE` instead of picking the date from the source table. I've disabled all the triggers which are responsible for it, even after its picking the `SYSDATE`. Can anybody suggest why this would be?

```
     update el_address b
   set last_update_date =
       (select last_update_date
          from gis_prod.ev_address a
         where a.feat_num = b.feat_num
           and not (a.g_version != 0 and a.g_next_version is null)
           and a.feat_num not in (select feat_num
                                    from gis_prod.ev_address
                                   where feat_num in (select feat_num
                                                        from gis_prod.ev_address
                                                       group by feat_num
                                                      having count(feat_num) > 1)
                                     and g_next_version < 0));
```

Comment: there's most probably still a trigger running

Comment: client system and server timing is different

Answer (score 0):

If

```
select max (last_update_date) from gis_prod.ev_address
```

is a date older than sysdate. The updated value can not come from the posted query.

Probably a trigger you've missed.

Comment: select max (last_update_date) from gis_prod.ev_address =15-NOV-17 so its definitely not older than SYSDATE.